# JNI return Date

Tags: java, android, c++, c, java-native-interface

I have JNI method that operates with `const struct tm myTimeInfo`. At the end, I would like to return result to Java. However, I cannot directly return `Date`. So far I convert `struct tm` to `jstring` and in java back to `Date`, which seems odd. Is there a way how to return directly `Date` filled with `struct tm`?

My current solution is something like:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL package_getTimeLineEndUTC(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    const struct tm timeInfo = generateTime();
    return env->NewStringUTF(asctime(&timeInfo));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning a string, you can return a `long`, i.e milliseconds since the epoch:

```
const struct tm timeInfo = generateTime();
return mktime(&timeInfo) * 1000;
```

Then use `Date(long date)` on the java side.